# Direct proof of unique invariant distribution for ergodic, positive-recurrent Markov chain

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, probability-theory, markov-chains

The following *ergodic theorem* is well known.

> **Ergodic Theorem.** Let $X$ be an ergodic (ie, irreducible and aperiodic) Markov chain on a countable state space $I$. Suppose that $X$ has an invariant distribution—$\pi$, say. Let $\mu$ be any distribution on $I$. Then,
>
> $$ \mathbb P_i(X_t = j) \to \pi_j \quad\text{as}\quad t \to \infty \quad\text{for all}\quad i,j \in I. $$
>
> In particular, since the limit exists, the invariant distribution is unique.

This is the way that I have seen uniqueness of the invariant distribution proved, eg via a coupling argument. It seems to me, though, that a direct, more algebraic, proof should exist.

> *Prove uniqueness of the invariant distirbution by direct, algebraic methods, not appealing to the probabilistic interpretation.*

After all, it's just a system of linear equations! I haven't been able to find one, but below are some of my thoughts on the matter. They're not super insightful, though...

1. Irreducibility is necessary, but aperiodicity isn't

   - $\pi P = P \iff \pi (I + P)/2 = \pi$, so can just make the chain lazy
   - this is great, since *irreducibility* implies that $-1$ is not an eigenvalue, but I'm not sure how to interpret *aperiodicity* algebraically
   - in fact, this lazification implies that we may assume that all eigenvalues of $P$ are non-negative—even strictly positive if we prefer, using $(2I + P)/3$
2. $\pi P = P \iff \pi(I - P) = 0 \iff (I - P^T) \pi^T = 0$

   - so, we want to show that $I - P^T$ has a one-dimensional kernel
   - this is equivalent to showing that the multiplicity of eigenvalue $1$ of $P^T$ is $1$
3. An invariant distribution can be constructed via the expected return times

   - this is just a *sufficient* condition for $\pi P = \pi$ to hold
   - I'm after a *necessary* condition
4. Naturally, I've also searched a lot online, including SE, but have not been successful

If anyone can point me to a good reference online, or give a proof—or even an outline—that would be appreciated!

Comment: Crossposted to [MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/451864/direct-proof-of-unique-invariant-distribution-for-ergodic-positive-recurrent-ma)

Comment: Solved by Jochen Glueck: https://mathoverflow.net/a/451868/509687. Go give their answer +1! 